How to make ruff complain about useless return statements in functions annotated to return not None?
Today, I went to Ruff playground, enabled PLR1711 (useless-return) rule  and pasted this code:
def f() -> int:
    print()
    return None

In Diagnostics tab I saw only Everything is looking good!.
I then removed  -> int for the code to be:
def f():
    print()
    return None

and saw Useless `return` statement at end of function (PLR1711) [Ln 3, Col 5].
Ruff complained in the same way when I annotated function to return None:
def f() -> None:
    print()
    return None

All the same goes for cases with return instead of return None.
Is this an intended behavior? If it is, I think the documentation on this rule should inform about this.
I have checked how pylint handles such cases by running cell with the following in fresh google colab runtime:
!pip install pylint>/dev/null
!printf 'def f() -> int:\n    print()\n    return None' > a.py
!pylint --version && pylint --disable C a.py

I got
pylint 3.3.1
astroid 3.3.5
Python 3.10.12 (main, Sep 11 2024, 15:47:36) [GCC 11.4.0]
************* Module a
a.py:1:0: R1711: Useless return at end of function or method (useless-return)

-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 6.67/10

So how can I get ruff to complain about useless return statements in cases when function is annotated to return not None? Do we have to wait for an update for this?
You can also help on github

Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77313860/ruff-doesnt-catch-undefined-argument-to-function

I think the idea is that ruff assumes such a statement is purposeful. For the first example, that’s a type error - a function that is declared to return int shouldn’t return None, and a type checker will flag that. In cases where the function can optionally return None (e.g. -> int | None), using return None is stylistically preferred as it is explicit.

@nneonneo Maybe it assumes that, but it should allow configuring ifself so that it flags that. A type checker will not necessarily flag that. It can be configured to not do so. PyCharm 2024.3 does not flag it with my current settings, for example. Such return is "stylistically preferred" when function actually returns None? Is it the case for everybody? Well, no, this is not the case for me. And I want to be able to configure ruff so that it does not allow such returns. And I think the docs on PLR1711 should mention that it behaves this way.

@nneonneo I dont know what -> int | None you are talking about. Looks like pyright thinks that this function: def a() -> int: ...; return None returns just int

Pretty sure a type checker will flag if a function that is declared to return int actually goes and returns None (or falls off the end and implicitly returns None). I would be very curious to see the example of PyCharm not flagging such an issue (while still having type-checking enabled). A function that can return either int or None should be tagged as returning int | None (or Union[int, None] in older Pythons).

Anywho, you can see the exact logic of Ruff here: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/blob/abb34828bdbce0eff28d4350b8f188436e57be78/crates/ruff_linter/src/rules/pylint/rules/useless_return.rs#L45. This spells out exactly the conditions for PLR1711 to be detected. You might have a case for "exact compatibility with PyLint", but I suspect (based on the discussion in the GitHub) that it might not actually go very far. Your other option is to just fork Ruff and edit the rules to your liking.

@nneonneo pycharm doesnt complain about this in my case: def a() -> int: return None . How do I check if I have type-checking enabled?
